# Why are only a few actions available on my triggers page?

Tags: actions, rules

I'm customising the content publishing flow of my site using actions and triggers. Unfortunately I've got a problem that not all the actions are show on the triggers page.

For example on 
I have: ["Choose an action", "Make content sticky", "Make content unsticky", "Promote content to front page", "Publish content", "Remove content from front page", "Unpublish content", "Change workflow state of post to next state", "Ban IP address of current user", "Block current user"]

Whereas on all other trigggers I only have these actions available:
["Choose an action", "Delete archived revisions", "Publish the most recent pending revision", "Change workflow state of post to next state", "Ban IP address of current user", "Block current user"]

Does anyone know why all actions are not shown for all available triggers?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The solution is to use the RULES module which is the successor of Triggers. If you want to use Triggers anyway (you shouldn't as my impression is it is being phased out and migrated to RULES) you would have to do code modifications (via drupal hooks).

With Rules, you can have all these options about publication of nodes and even more.